# Can't access to Ubuntu 13.04 after installing it alongside with windows 7

Tags: 13.04, windows-7

after installing Ubuntu 13.04 alongside with windows 7,my laptop restarted but entered to windows 7 without letting me choose between 7 & Ubuntu !!

my laptop (Lenovo G580)

Answer (score 2):

Did you (re)install Windows after installing Linux?

You have to repair the grub boot-loader (or replace it with another boor loader).  Repair-Boot https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair seems to be the best option.

Comment: I cant enter to ubuntu !!

Comment: @user189566 you don't need to be able to boot into Ubutnu to use boot repair.  All you need to do is boot from your liveDVD/USB click "Try Ubuntu" and then follow the direction on installing and using boot repair. The steps for using the liveDVD are option 2 on the webpage that was linked.